# Python - How to replace multiple `with` statement blocks by a single `with` statement block

Tags: python, with-statement

Consider the following piece of Python code:

```
with open('reviews.txt', 'r') as f:
    reviews = f.read()
with open('labels.txt', 'r') as f:
    labels = f.read()
```

The goal is to replace the two `with` statements with a single `with` statement.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please elaborate on "combine the two different file openings".  It's a bit vague.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? Just to make your code shorter? Are you expecting any other advantage?

Comment: The advantage is more mental in that a single `with` statement corresponds to the thought 'get the reviews and labels'.

Comment: @BryanOakley Terry's comment summarises my motivation. It makes the code cleaner, succinct and easier to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple `open` commands if you separate them by comma:

```
with open('reviews.txt', 'r') as f1, open('labels.txt', 'r') as f2:
    reviews = f1.read()
    labels = f2.read()
```